# Want to cleanup my .gradle folder in root, can i safely delete previous old versions folders?

Tags: gradle

I want to cleanup my `.gradle` folder but want to do it safely, without affecting my new gradle version.

When I go to my `.gradle` folder, there is 6 folders inside:

```
build-scan-data
caches
daemon
native
notifications
wrapper
```

When I type `gradle -v`, I get following version: `5.6.2`.

In `caches` folder I have these files/folders:

```
4.5.1
5.2.1
5.6.2
jars-3
journal-1
modules-2
transforms-1
transforms-2
user-id.txt
user-id.txt.lock
```

Can i remove folder `4.5.1` and `5.2.1` and leave the rest?

In `daemon` folder, I have these folders:

```
4.5.1
5.2.1
5.6.2
```

Can i remove both folders except `5.6.2`?

In `native folder` i have these folders:

```
25
28
29
30
jansi
```

What are these and do i need to remove something here?

In `notifications` folder, I have these folders:

```
5.2.1
5.5.1
5.6
5.6.2
```

Can i remove all expect `5.6.2` ?

And the last folder is `wrapper/dists`. In this folder i have these:

```
gradle-4.5.1-all
gradle-4.8-all
gradle-5.2.1-all
gradle-5.2.1-bin
gradle-5.6.2-bin
```

Can i remove all expect `gradle-5.6.2-bin` ?

Can i cleanup in this way without affecting anything with gradle 5.6.2 in my machine?

Thank for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

Should you really delete too much, Gradle will reload it. But the suggestions you made are safe, there shouldn't even be anything to reload. Leave the `native`.

Comment: I can also supplement this with saying that Gradle periodically deletes old distributions. So you generally don't have to worry about that.